# OS-Specific Applications

Tags: operating-system

I just want know why some games are only Windows-based and won't run on other OSs like Mac OS X and Linux. What makes them different, and how does the program know that the OS is Windows, Linux, or Mac?
Also, similarly, why won't a Windows 7 32-bit driver work on 64-bit and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Besides how Mac and Linux use a different executable type (they use Mach-O and ELF, as far as I've seen) than Windows (PE), if the executable loader was able to parse everything and load it into memory, many things can go wrong. Library calls, such as `printf(3)` rely on underlying system calls, which calls the kernel of the OS. In the case of printf(3), it calls `fstat(2)`, `sbrk(2)` and `write(2)`. (Note that this is the case under the `newlib` library; I am unsure about the other standard C libraries.) As far as you know, the system call interface for Windows can be very different from the one Linux uses, and Windows may even be missing a few system calls that Linux has (like `fork(2)`)

Comment: Thanks, For the reply. What about the drivers we use for Windows ? How exactly a drivers for mouse only activates a mouse not a keyboard?